# java Constructor of class Printwriter

Tags: java, wildcard, printwriter

In one of the sample code I saw, there is such a line:

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("$$$temp$$$.$$$");
```

What is the `"$"` sign mean in this context? Is it something like a wildcard?

Comment: I don't think so, could you put the link of the sample

Comment: The way to look for such an answer is look at the Documentation, find the method or constructor that matches the type of the argument most closely (in this case, the constructor that takes a string) and see if the `$` character is mentioned as having any particular meaning.

Comment: @Bzil It is an example from my teacher, so no link.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I checked, however, there was nothing mentioned about $, as far as I could see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$` means nothing in particular which is why its appears to being used here to specify a temporary file name. Chances are a file with this name will not already exist on the filesystem. If you're trying to create a temporary file check out [`createTempFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createTempFile-java.nio.file.Path-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-)

Comment: But why is $ used in this example? Would it be the same if it was: PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("temp");

Comment: obviously there are 2 different filenames - the original one has an obscure name probably to avoid writing to an existing file (probably what your [teacher intended](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32143069/java-constructor-of-class-printwriter/32143143?noredirect=1#comment52204292_32143069) ;))

Comment: Thank you for answering. Just to make sure if my understanding is correct: so $ is added in order to avoid write to a file named "temp" should it exists?

Answer (score 0):

It's the constructor [`PrintWriter(String filename)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter(java.lang.String)), which implies that `"$$$temp$$$.$$$"` is a filename of some type.

Comment: What is the difference between "$$$temp$$$.$$$" and "temp" in this context?

Comment: None.  They're both strings which, according to their usage, should point to a file with the same name.  If they don't, then the code will raise an exception complaining that it cannot find file specified.